# Rails doesn’t persist flash message key after destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 4, and have four methods at my `application_controller.rb` for setting flash messages in Rails

```
def exclusion_info_for model_name
  flash[:notice] = "#{model_name.to_s.capitalize} has been deleted."
end

def creation_notice_for model_name
  flash[:notice] = "#{model_name.to_s.capitalize} has been created."
end

def update_notice_for model_name
  flash[:notice] = "#{model_name.to_s.capitalize} has been updated."
end

def error_notice
  flash[:error] = "An unexpected error has it occurred"
end
```

But the `flash` setting at `exclusion_notice_for` is lost after redirection of the action `destroy`. The others methods works normally.

**The Controller**

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def new
    respond_with @customer = customer
  end

  def create
    if @customer = Customer.create(customer_attrs)
      creation_notice_for :customer
    else
      error_notice
    end
    respond_with @customer, location: "/"
  end

  def show
    respond_with @customer = customer
  end

  def index
    respond_with @customers = Customer.all
  end

  def edit
    respond_with @customer = customer
  end

  def update
    if @customer = customer.update(customer_attrs)
      update_notice_for :customer
    else
      error_notice
    end
    respond_with @customer, location: "/"
  end

  def destroy
    if @customer = customer.destroy()
      exclusion_info_for :customer
    else
      error_notice
    end
    respond_with @customer, location: "/"
  end

  private

  def customer
    id ? Customer.find(id) : Customer.new
  end

  def customer_attrs
    params.require(:customer).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

This is the application destroy button currently genereted

This is the `application.rb` file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include FormattedTime

  def form_parent
    ObjectSpace._id2ref(params[:form_parent_object_id].to_i) if params[:form_parent_object_id]
  end
  helper_method :form_parent

  def root
    render "layouts/application", layout: false
  end

  protected

  def id
    params[:id]
  end

  # refactored
  def info_flashed model_name, action
    flash[:notice] = "#{model_name.to_s.capitalize} has been #{action}."
  end

  def error_notice
    flash[:error] = "An unexpected error has it occurred"
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your controller code.

Comment: @PetrGazarov updated :)

Comment: @LucasNelson i try, but does’t works.

Comment: @LucasNelson yeah, it’s the deleted line, so, no, doesn’t show 404 error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flashing Method will work all of your actions simply add `'created'` or `'updated'` string like in destroy method.

You had error `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

You can put this method in **application.rb** file to fix it all.

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception,    if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

protected

def info_flashed (model_name, action)
  flash[:notice] = "#{model_name.to_s.capitalize} has been #{action}."
end
```

**In Controller**

```
  def destroy
    if @customer = customer.destroy
      info_flashed (@customer, 'deleted') 
    else
      error_notice
    end
    respond_with @customer, location: "/" # you need to redirect correct path.
  end
```

Comment: Just add ```protected``` on methods?

Comment: in `application.rb` under protected line.

Comment: I understand, but it did not work :(

**Obs.**: don’t insert spaces between method name and ```(```

```info_flashed(``` it’s ok, ```info_fleshed (``` an error is raised

Comment: what kind error u getting ? Can u post `server log` ?

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo, r u actually able to `create/update` ? because i see you have totally different issue.

Comment: Yeah, it works on create/update. The record it’s saved, and the ```flash[:notice]``` works. In destroy, only the record it’s deleted.

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo, Can u post your `application.rb` file and that `destroy` button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108236/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-rafael-laurindo).